# Excel VBA - Expression Value loses type and value after true IF Statement

Tags: vba, excel

I am having trouble with hiding/unhiding rows. For some reason, if either of the IF statements ends up being true, then the expression value "i", loses its value and type and I get a type mismatch error. If I don't have i in the code and just use the straight numbers, then everything runs dandy. I cannot seem to figure out how to fix this, any suggestions? Thanks!

Here is the code in question

```
Sub Macro1()
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer

'Initial Conditions
i = 4
j = 184

If Range("A2").Value = "ONLINE" Then
ActiveSheet.Rows("i:184").EntireRow.Hidden = False
End If

If Range("A2").Value = "OFFLINE" Then
ActiveSheet.Rows("i:184").EntireRow.Hidden = True
End If

End Sub​
```

Comment: How did you get this to work `("i:184")`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ActiveSheet.Rows("i:184")` - This passes the character `i` to `Rows` which is not valid.

To use the `i` *variable* change to `ActiveSheet.Rows(i & ":184")` or for `i` and `j` `ActiveSheet.Rows(i & ":" & j)`.

Comment: In terms of posting the answer you are faster than me, but my comment is early ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 'provide the correct Column names as per your needs
 ActiveSheet.Range("A" & i & ":C" & j).EntireRow.Hidden
```

[ActiveSheet.Rows()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff821382.aspx) property doesn't take a parameter which is a string value, produced in your code. e.g. Rows("i:184"), that's an invalid parameter with an invalid type. Therefore the **type-mismatch error**.

If active sheet no longer refers to what you initially point it to, these Rows(4:184) like will not work. Therefore you should always use the explicit declarations by `Range` object of worksheet.

For a cleaner code, you may use it like this.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Hide_Seek
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range
Dim checkVal as String

Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet 1") 'whatever your sheet is
Set rng = ws.Range("A4") 'whatever starting cell, in your case it's D

'assuming these values do change    
i = 4
j = 184

'this is now resizing the range to your desired range, starting from the 
'initial range you defined
'Resize(Row, Column)
Set rng = rng.Resize(i, j)

checkVal = ws.Range("A2").Value
If checkVal = "ONLINE" then
   rng.EntireRow.Hidden = False
Elseif checkVal = "OFFLINE" then
   rng.EntireRow.Hidden = True
End If

End Sub
```